# ¿Cómo puedo insertar un caracter cada cierta posición en un string en C#?

Tags: c#, formato, insert

Qué tal, buenas tardes.

Tengo una cadena que contiene varios digitos en hexadecimal y quisiera separarlo por bytes con un guión.
He utilizado el `string.insert()` y funciona, el problema es que son hasta 16 bytes y son muchos insert para eso.
Pensé en hacer un ciclo con los insert, pero no sé si sería la mejor manera.
¿Hay algún otro modo más fácil?
¿Tal vez con string.Format()?

Este es la forma en que lo he hecho, pero como ven es demasiado largo:

```
string hex = "000102030405060708090A0B";
string cadena = hex.Insert(22, "-").Insert(20, "-").Insert(18, "-").Insert(16, "-").Insert(14, "-").Insert(12, "-").Insert(10, "-").Insert(8, "-").Insert(6, "-").Insert(4, "-").Insert(2, "-");
```

Gracias de antemano.
¡Saludos!

Comment: saludos Emmanuel, coloca el código que has intentado para poder ayudarte :D Bienvenido a SOes. Saludos :D

Comment: Oh, okay. Lo siento. Ahora mismo lo pongo.

Comment: normal hermano, todos aprendemos :D te faltó agregar lo que contiene la variable TD, entre más detalles, mayor % de éxito de tener una buena respuesta :D

Comment: Listo, para simplificarlo puse un ejemplo de lo que tiene. Muchas gracias por los comentarios. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

usando `regex`

```
cadena=Regex.Replace(hex, "(.{2})(?!$)", "$0-");
```

cualquier caracter `.` 2 veces `{2}`

```
.{2}
```

si `?` no `!` es el final de la linea `$`

```
?!$
```

Comment: Muy buena propuesta, el problema es que al final de la cadena agrega un guión también.

Comment: ok, si ya vi... per don, deja lo acomodo

Comment: Ese sí lo deja perfecto. ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3):

Puedes utilizar el método `Range` de `Enumerable` para separar la cadena en grupos de dos caracteres y `string.Join` para concatenarlos utilizando el guión como separador:

```
    var datos = "F4DA023BA23560AC";

    var bytes =  Enumerable.Range(0, datos.Length / 2)
        .Select(i => datos.Substring(i * 2, 2));
    Debug.WriteLine(string.Join("-", bytes));
```

Comment: Muy buena opción, pero creo que la respuesta de Jorge me ayudará más. En realidad comienzo con un arreglo de bytes y con una función lo convierto a hexadecimal que me resulta en una cadena. Con esta solución los separaría de nuevo y volvería a unirlos. ¡Muchas gracias!